# DFM: Derived Form contains derived Bitmaps

Tags: c++, c++builder

**Using C++ Builder XE7**

I have a base form with a TImageList object

```
object FormBase: TFormBase
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'FormBase'
  ClientHeight = 200
  ClientWidth = 329
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Left = 32
    Top = 24
    Bitmap = {
      494C010101007800180010001000FFFFFFFFFF00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF424D3600
      snipped
      00000000000000000000000000000000}
  end
end
```

Deriving TFormBase I note that the Bitmap of TImageList ist copied to the derived form:

```
inherited FormBase1: TFormBase1
  Caption = 'FormBase1'
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  inherited ImageList1: TImageList
    Bitmap = {
      494C010101007800180010001000FFFFFFFFFF00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF424D3600
      snipped
      00000000000000000000000000000000}
  end
end
```

Do I have now in my application two identical Imagelists??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's interesting.

At runtime, there will only be a single `TImageList` allocated for each `TFormBase`, so at that level, you only have one `TImageList` object.

However, based on those DFMs, your executable FILE will contain two copies of the bitmap data - one for `TFormBase` and a second for `TFormBase1`. This makes your executable file bigger (which is bad) and will slightly slow the creation time for `TFormBase1` (as the bitmap data gets loaded twice). I think all DFM resources stay in memory, so it's also using more memory than is necessary.

Try manually editing the derived DFM to remove the `bitmap={...}` section, and see if the executable shrinks (and if program behaviour stays the same!).

Comment: Removing "Bitmap = {...}" does not have any influence. It appears again next time opening the DFM. I think one should avoid to use Bitmaps on forms and store them on a TDataModul.

Comment: There is another point I realized: There are sometimes deleted Controls left in the DFM!!!